# type casting to a dynamic array

Tags: delphi, delphi.net, delphi-2005

Given the following:

```
Type
  TSomeTypeArray = array of SomeType;

var
  anArray: array of SomeType;

function GetSomeTypeArray: TSomeTypeArray;
```

I want to write `anArray = GetSomeTypeArray();` but the compiler does not like it.
Without changing the type of `anArray` or the return type of `GetSomeTypeArray`how can I typecast `TSomeTypeArray` to `array of SomeType`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. You need to declare `anArray` as of type `TSomeTypeArray`, then it should work.

Alternatively, you could store the result into another array of type `TSomeTypeArray` then call `SetLength` on `anArray` to the length of the returned array. And finally loop through the two arrays setting the elements of `anArray` to the elements of the returned array.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. AFAIK that is the only way, and since no one else piped in with an alternative . . .

Answer (score 6):

You could typecast the left hand side of the assignment:

```
TSomeTypeArray(anArray) := GetSomeTypeArray();
```

Comment: Left hand side typecast <- this blows my mind so much